# Magento 2: Admin Attention Something went wrong

Tags: magento2, admin, error, exception, runtime

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0

I already referred Magento SO post with the same error.

When I'm going to Edit Any of the Product then while loading it's giving this error. Below are the details of log files

`var\log\debug.log`

> [2016-09-30 02:15:53] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:
>   {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false}
>   []
>       [2016-09-30 02:15:59] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http://localhost/magento2/admin/catalog/product/edit/id/2048/set/16/type/simple/store/0/key/83d52c6cd14f1a381e2ceadbc0485a387f7e57f44c790eeff40a79e21f5dbd0a/back/edit/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false}
>   []

`var\log\system.log`

> [2016-09-30 02:16:07] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout:
>   LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE0_3a828e091252a8ca686703b2c072394bd and handles
>   default, catalog_product_edit, catalog_product_simple: Please correct
>   the XML data and try again. [] [] [2016-09-30 02:16:07] main.INFO:
>   Cache file with merged layout:
>   LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE0_3cf9ab1b1723bedc1dcd665a812b00335 and handles
>   admin-1column: Please correct the XML data and try again. [] []
>   [2016-09-30 02:16:07] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header'
>   tries to reorder itself towards 'global.notices', but their parents
>   are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. []
>   [] [2016-09-30 02:16:07] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the
>   'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications',
>   but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper'
>   respectively. [] [] [2016-09-30 02:16:07] main.CRITICAL: Broken
>   reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards
>   'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and
>   'header' respectively. [] [] [2016-09-30 02:16:07] main.INFO: Cache
>   file with merged layout:
>   LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE0_36f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles
>   catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again. []
>   [] [2016-09-30 02:16:09] main.INFO: Item
>   Magento_Backend::system_currency was removed [] []

Comment: which version have you used for magento?

Comment: Updated in Question @Rakesh Please check

Comment: Hi @J. Chomel u put Bounty On this Awsome?

Comment: Just trying to help. This costs nothing!

Comment: Have you modify catalog module or add any module related to catalog product, May be some issue available in your custom module related to catalog product

Comment: @Rakesh Yes i put my custom code on catalog module & also override that.

Comment: just disable this moudle and check again

Comment: @Rakesh Good suggestion. Sometimes will go so much advance. We forgot basic thing :)

Comment: if your custom module code disable at that time your code is working for product default functionality, right?

Comment: It suppose to be @Rakesh didn't checked it

Comment: you have to first disable your code and check further, may be its create issue, if those code create issue, you have to debug your code for why stuck admin details page, OR just your code here to debug more info

Comment: @AnkitShah May i know how did you solve this error?

Answer (score 4):

### Regarding the debug file

So the messages like this `main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate` in Magento 2 are not errors, there are only debug messages to tell that the cache is invalidated (which is not a problem nor an error).

### Regarding the system file

So the messages like this `Broken reference: the 'block1' tries to reorder itself towards 'block2'` is not a real error either. As you can see from this github issue:

> Ok, guys. There is no bug here ) Really. There are two reasons, why
>   you all see such a logs.
>
> Reason 1 People keep forgetting remove "before" and "after" attributes
>   for blocks which have been moved to another parent, so those are no
>   longer relevant. Internal ticket in progress MAGETWO-53410 and we will
>   clean up legacy references soon.
>
> Reason 2 As an example, let's take  Such references mostly (if not all) reside
>   in default.xml files (so will be applied to all pages without
>   exclusions), while the container "sidebar.additional” is added by
>   2columns-left.xml layout only. So, on pages where different page
>   layout is used, the reference will lead to nowhere, and you will see
>   CRITICAL error logged (while it is not critical at all).
>
> The tricky thing is that sometimes that could be a normal case and
>   developer understands why it happens (if want to add a block to
>   specific container to all pages on which target container available,
>   and don’t need that block to be added to the pages where target
>   container is not available).
>
> Short excerpt from internal ticket description: "Stop logging such
>   cases at all, or at least stop marking them as CRITICAL (ensure that
>   it’s not logged in production mode). Also it will be helpful if logged
>   message will say the URL of the page where target container is
>   missed".
>
> So, as you see, we still think that logging such "broken" references
>   is a right thing to do, since some of them are really could be caused
>   by misspells in layout files.

I reckon there was a lot of errors like this in the logs in the early stable releases as you can see from those two issues:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3075
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3224

So if you wanna get rid of them, I reckon you should update to the last version. Seems like Magento fixed it in the `develop` branch but I'm not sure if the bug fixes are part of 2.0.8/2.1.1 already.

Comment: @Raphale Can't fix in my current Version?

Comment: @AnkitShah as I said try to update to 2.1.1 and see if that's fixed. I am using 2.1.1 and I don't have those errors anymore. If you still have them and installed Magento 2 via GitHub you can pull the `develop` branch where it seems to be fixed ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Is possible magento 2.0.0 theme used for Magento 2.1.7

Answer (score 1):

These annoying and absolutely useless messages are generated by function **execute()** in **\Magento\Framework\Cache\InvalidateLogger**

```
/**
 * Logger invalidate cache
 * @param mixed $invalidateInfo
 * @return void
 */
public function execute($invalidateInfo)
{
    $this->logger->debug('cache_invalidate: ', $this->makeParams($invalidateInfo));
}
```

### I use simple fix to get rid of it:

Extend InvalidateLogger in your module:

```
   /**
     * Cache configuration model. Provides cache configuration data to the application
     *
     * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    namespace Vendor\Module\Magento\Framework\Cache;

    class InvalidateLogger extends \Magento\Framework\Cache\InvalidateLogger
    {
        /**
         * Logger invalidate cache
         * @param mixed $invalidateInfo
         * @return void
         */
        public function execute($invalidateInfo)
        {
            // Stop spamming in my log
        }
    }
```

And add mapping to di.xml of you module:

```
<!-- Disable Logger invalidate cache -->
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Cache\InvalidateLogger"
            type="Vendor\Module\Magento\Framework\Cache\InvalidateLogger"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I only need to disable this line on a development server (and I will not get an update of the code), I have enabled myself to comment out some core code in Magento ***(quick dirty temp fix)***

I have commented out the line

```
public function execute($invalidateInfo)
{
    //this line : 
    //$this->logger->debug('cache_invalidate: ', $this->makeParams($invalidateInfo)); 
}
```

in

```
vendor/magento/framework/Cache/InvalidateLogger.php
```