# Cache invalidate issue

Tags: magento2, cache, log, debug

in debug.log i see following entries:

```
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:      {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":     
["CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":
["LAYOUT_GENERAL_CACHE_TAG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":  
["BLOCK_HTML"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":  
["COLLECTION_DATA"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":    
["REFLECTION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":   
["DB_DDL"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":
["EAV"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":  
["CUSTOMER_NOTIFICATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":
["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":
["INTEGRATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":
["INTEGRATION_API_CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":
["TRANSLATE"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":
["WEBSERVICE"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_design_config_grid_flat_1"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_design_config_grid_flat_2"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_design_config_grid_flat_3"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-11-11 21:59:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_design_config_grid_flat_4"},"is_exception":false} []
```

Why cache is invalidate, even i clear and flush cache ?

Comment: See this: https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Cache-invalidate/td-p/25224

Comment: It has been answered in http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138786/magento-2-admin-attention-something-went-wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: Admin Attention Something went wrong](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138786/magento-2-admin-attention-something-went-wrong)

Answer (score 2):

as @PrimalBurgh said, this are not error.

```
[2017-01-01 12:00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://example.com/product-name.html","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
```

This simply suggest that cache has been invalidated. 
This debug logs are printed in following conditions -

- If a page is opened first time i.e no cache and cache is created for first time
- if the cache interval is ended and new cache is generated

Comment: How to solve the issue in other ways? @Arun Karnawat

Answer (score 1):

These are not errors, they are just saying that the cache has been invalidated. If these are the only messages you are seeing in any log files. You can turn off logging to stop them coming out if they are a problem.